# Asp net core 2.0 controller handler not triggered via java-script ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post some data to a razor controller, I have two post handlers as shown in the source, one is the default one, another is named "OnPostFormalDealerNameAsync", I tried to use it to handle some post request, but I failed many times, everytime it simply trigger the default one, no matter how I change the url in the javascript. I am pretty new to asp.net, so I hope some one can help me out. Many thanks.

```js
function getFormalDealerName(e)
    {
        var token = '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ShoesMarket/Shoes2Dealer/dealers",
            headers:
                {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": token
                },
            data: dealer_str,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {


                } else {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },

        });
    }
```

```html
namespace ShoesSystem.Pages.ShoesMarket.Shoes2Dealer
{
    [Authorize]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ShoesSystem.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(ShoesSystem.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
       
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
           ...
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            ...
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("Shoes2Dealer/Dealers")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostFormalDealerNameAsync()
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem following the post here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-web-api-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-core/

I create a api, and thing solved.